# How to use FontAwesome in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, font-awesome

[**FontAwesome**](http://fontawesome.io/) makes adding editable icons into HTML fairly easy:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>
```

I have tried adding a **FontAwesome** icon to a Qt widget, but it doesn't show:

```
QPushButton *qB = new QPushButton("TXT");
qB -> setProperty("class", "fa fa-camera-retro");
```

How can I go about it to make it work with Qt widgets?

Comment: How are you inserting the resources into the application? Have you download them and inserted as resources in a .qrc file? What about the stylesheet of the application?

Comment: You can use QtAwesome Project: https://github.com/gamecreature/QtAwesome, it allows you to create QIcon from fa code. Ex: menuAction->setIcon( awesome->icon(fa::beer).pixmap(32,32) );

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Qt doesn't work like that.
You need to create a qrc file and bundle FontAwesome to your project, like this:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/">
    <file alias="FontAwesome.otf">FontAwesome.otf</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Then include it in the .pro file:

```
RESOURCES += resources.qrc
```

Then load it and use it, like this, providing the unicode character of the icon you intend to display:

```
if (QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/FontAwesome.otf") < 0)
    qWarning() << "FontAwesome cannot be loaded !";

QFont font;
font.setFamily("FontAwesome");
font.setPixelSize(32);

ui->pushButton->setFont(font);
ui->pushButton->setText("\uf083");
```

In your case, the camera icon code is [indicated here](http://fontawesome.io/icon/camera-retro/)

Result:

[image]

Comment: Nitpick: using the Qt Resource system is optional. It's a good idea, but it's not always a necessary one. E.g. on OS X you may wish to leverage the application bundle instead.

Comment: You can get the header file defining the icon code points from  [IconFontCppHeaders on Github](https://github.com/juliettef/IconFontCppHeaders)

    #include "IconsFontAwesome.h"
 
    ui->pushButton->setText( ICON_FA_CAMERA_RETRO );

Comment: How did u find unicode character for given icon ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking to do the same with Qt5 and the last version of FontAwesome 5.x. After some research, I found a very simple class in GitHub for using Font Icon in Qt 5 and Qt 6 projects with QWidget. This class provides helpers to use Font awesome (v4.7, v5.15 and v6.0) and Google Material Icon (v4).

The code is very small and provides all the functions needed to display icons in QPushButton, QToolButton, etc.

Here, the GitHub link : https://github.com/philvl/ZFontIcon.

Comment: Can you embedded the related code in the answer rather than link to the code base. I think that will help fellow users understand exactly what code solves the problem.

Comment: Is there a way to add these types to QML?